# Is there a function for iterating through a vector irrespective of its type?

Tags: c++, vector

In my program I have multiple vectors that I loop through such as:

```
std::vector<Config*>::iterator itbegin = configs_with_new_parameters.begin();
std::vector<Config*>::iterator itend = configs_with_new_parameters.end();
for (auto i = itbegin; i < itend; ++i)
{
    Config* config = (*i);
    addParameterData(config);
}
```

It'd be nice to have a function that I can call that can iterate any vector type, not just Config* as in this example:

```
Config* IterateVector(std::vector<Config*> *list)
{
    std::vector<Config*>::iterator itbegin = list->begin();
    std::vector<Config*>::iterator itend = list->end();
    for (auto i = itbegin; i < itend; ++i)
    {
        return *i; //??
    }
}
```

And for each iteration, some operation will need to be done. Would it be correct to somehow return each iteration and do the operation outside the function?

Sorry in advance for the ambiguity.

Comment: Looks like you want [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Comment: Didn't `auto config = (*i);` work for you?

Comment: there are many of such functions, if you dont know them it is high time to look at the algorithms in the standard library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: As NathanOliver says... Or write a template function?

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to write a function that will take any type of vector.

```
template<typename T>
void doStuff(std::vector<T>& data)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

Using the range based for looping over a vector is easy:

```
    for(auto& item: data)
    {
         // Do stuff
    }
```

If you want to apply a function to each item in the vector you can pass a functor as a parameter to function. When calling the function you simply use a lambda to define the functor.

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void doStuffWithFunc(std::vector<T>& data, A&& action)
{
    for(auto& item: data)
    {
         action(item);
    }
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
std::vector<int>   data {1,2,3,4,5,6};
doStuffWithFunc(data, [](int val){std::cout << val << "\n";});
```